# unable to get all users from laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

my controller is RegisterController which is in controller in auth folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'middle_name' => 'string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|',
        'user_status' => 'required|max:255',
        'user_role' => 'required|max:255',
        'user_type' => 'required|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|max:255',
        'address' => 'required|max:255',
      ]);
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $request['first_name'],
        'middle_name' => $request['middle_name'],
        'last_name' => $request['last_name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
        'user_status' => $request['user_status'],
        'user_role' =>$request['user_role'],
        'user_type' =>$request['user_type'],
        'phone' =>$request['phone'],
        'address' =>$request['address'],
    ]);
}
public function index(){
    return User::all();
}
```

}

And my api.php file in routes folder is

```
Route::get('/users','Auth\RegisterController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

I want to all data from user table which code is in  Auth\Regitercontroller in index function this route returns

```
{
 "error":"unauthenticated", 
}
```

so i want aall user from table user and if i remove middleware->('auth:api') from routes then i got all users but i want middleware in routes for security reason so help me.Thank You

Comment: So log in and see what happens. You have `->middleware('auth');` on the route

Comment: i m using api. and this gives error:unauthenticated

Comment: You are using authenticate middleware so you have to first login and then check /users path. Also, If you are using API then there might be some token (JWT) based authentication. Your error clearly indicates that you are not authenticated. So you have to log in first if you use auth middleware.

Comment: @PassionInfinite i m using passport for token . from this token i only get single user details but i want to reterive all users what can i do please.